# Strange Behavior in React JS

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to render a function component in an Array.map loop, When I delete the first element of the Array it re-renders the main component, and instead of showing the remaining Array elements it removes the last element from the UI! (The deleted element stays on the UI!)

I am sure that I am deleting the correct element. I have correctly used key={index} in the Array.map function. I tried to console.log the elements that are being rendered to the DOM in the Array.map and it shows the correct elements! But the UI is different from what is logged!!!

```
// index.tsx

/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import React, {
  forwardRef,
  useImperativeHandle,
  Ref,
  useRef,
  useState,
} from "react";
// @ts-ignore
import ReactCursorPosition from "react-cursor-position";
import { EpicFileBlock } from "./components/block";
import {
  ClassesInterface,
  StylesInterface,
  EpicStylesProvider,
  EpicClassesProvider,
  Themes,
  Layouts,
} from "./lib/theme-provider";
import "./styles.module.css";

export interface EpicFileRef {
  addFiles: (files: File | FileList | File[]) => void;
  removeFiles: (...fileNames: string[]) => void;
  empty: () => void;
}

export interface EpicFileProps {
  ref?: Ref<EpicFileRef>;
  className?: ClassesInterface;
  style?: StylesInterface;
  name?: string;
  accept?: string[];
  multiple?: boolean;
  limit?: {
    min?: number;
    max?: number;
  };
  size?: {
    min?: number;
    max?: number;
  };
  enableImagePreview?: boolean;
  instantUpload?: boolean;
  title?: string;
  text?: string;
  actionText?: string;
  theme?: Themes;
  layout?: Layouts;
  disabled?: boolean;
}

export interface FileType {
  name: string;
  type: string;
  size: number;
  ref?: string;
  src?: string;
  file?: File;
}

export const EpicFile = forwardRef<EpicFileRef, EpicFileProps>(
  (
    {
      multiple,
      title,
      text,
      actionText,
      instantUpload,
      className,
      style,
      theme,
      layout,
      disabled,
    },
    Ref
  ) => {
    // Initialize Styles Provider
    const StylesProvider = new EpicStylesProvider(
      "epic-file",
      style,
      theme,
      layout
    );

    // Initialize Classes Provider
    const ClassesProvider = new EpicClassesProvider(className);

    // Use Styles
    const DefaultClasses = StylesProvider.useStyles();

    // Overridden Classes
    const Classes = ClassesProvider.useClasses(DefaultClasses);

    const BubbleRef = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null);

    const ShowBubble = (bubble: HTMLDivElement, X: number, Y: number) => {
      bubble.style.opacity = ".1";
      bubble.style.transform = "scale(1)";
      bubble.style.top = `${Y - 55}px`;
      bubble.style.left = `${X - 55}px`;
    };

    const HideBubble = (bubble: HTMLDivElement) => {
      bubble.style.opacity = "0";
      bubble.style.transform = "scale(3)";
    };

    const [Files, setFiles] = useState([] as Array<FileType>);

    const CreateNewFileType = (file: File, ref?: string): FileType => {
      return {
        name: file.name,
        type: file.type,
        size: file.size,
        ref,
        file,
      };
    };

    const AddFiles = (files: File | FileList | File[]) => {
      if (files instanceof File) files = [files];
      else if (files instanceof Array)
        files = files.filter((file) => file instanceof File);
      else if (files instanceof FileList) files = Array.from(files);

      // Add To Files State
      setFiles((list) => {
        // Collect Non Duplicate Files
        const FilesToAdd: File[] = [];

        // Filter Non Duplicate Files
        (files as File[]).forEach((file) => {
          if (!list.filter((fileType) => fileType.name === file.name).length)
            FilesToAdd.push(file);
        });

        // Add New Files
        FilesToAdd.forEach((file) => list.push(CreateNewFileType(file)));

        return [...list];
      });
    };

    const RemoveFiles = (...fileNames: string[]) => {
      setFiles((list) => {
        list = list.filter((file) => {
          if (fileNames.includes(file.name)) return false;
          else return true;
        });
        return [...list];
      });
    };

    const Empty = () => {
      setFiles([]);
    };

    // Put Methods to the Reference
    useImperativeHandle(Ref, () => ({
      addFiles: AddFiles,
      removeFiles: RemoveFiles,
      empty: Empty,
    }));

    const DefaultText = (
      <span>
        {text || `Drag & Drop your ${multiple ? "files" : "file"}, or`}{" "}
        <span className={Classes.action}>{actionText || "Browse"}</span>
      </span>
    );

    return (
      <div className={[Classes.mainContainer, theme].join(" ")}>
        <div ref={BubbleRef} className={[Classes.bubble, theme].join(" ")} />

        {/* Files Browser */}
        {multiple || !Files.length ? (
          <div className={Classes.inputContainer}>
            <input
              className={Classes.input}
              type="file"
              title={title || "Choose your file(s)"}
              onDragOver={(e) => {
                if (BubbleRef.current)
                  ShowBubble(
                    BubbleRef.current,
                    e.nativeEvent.x,
                    e.nativeEvent.y
                  );
              }}
              onDragLeave={() => {
                if (BubbleRef.current) HideBubble(BubbleRef.current);
              }}
              onChange={(e) => {
                if (BubbleRef.current) HideBubble(BubbleRef.current);
                e.persist();
                const Target = e.currentTarget;
                if (Target.files) AddFiles(Target.files);

                // Reset File Browser
                Target.value = "";
              }}
              multiple={multiple}
              disabled={disabled}
            />
            <p className={[Classes.text, theme].join(" ")}>{DefaultText}</p>
          </div>
        ) : (
          ""
        )}

        {/* File Blocks */}

        {/* Here is the Problem... */}

        <div className={Classes.blocksContainer}>
          {Files.map((fileType, index) => {
            console.log("List Item::", fileType.name);
            return (
              <EpicFileBlock
                index={index}
                key={index}
                fileType={fileType}
                instantUpload={instantUpload}
                theme={theme}
                layout={layout}
                Classes={Classes}
                remove={(f) => {
                  console.log("Deleting::", f.name);
                  RemoveFiles(f.name);
                }}
              />
            );
          })}
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
);
```

```
// ./components/block.tsx

/* eslint-disable prettier/prettier */
/* eslint-disable no-unused-vars */
import React, {
  forwardRef,
  useImperativeHandle,
  Fragment,
  useState,
} from "react";
import { Elements, Layouts, Themes } from "../lib/theme-provider";
import { motion } from "framer-motion";
import { FileType } from "..";
import { FiX, FiRotateCcw, FiUpload, FiSlash } from "react-icons/fi";

export interface EpicFileBlockProps {
  index: number;
  Classes: { [key in Elements]: string };
  fileType: FileType;
  instantUpload?: boolean;
  theme?: Themes;
  layout?: Layouts;
  remove?: (file: FileType) => void;
}

export interface EpicFileBlockRef {
  onAdd: (callback: (file: FileType) => Promise<void> | void) => void;
  onUpload: <T extends any>(
    callback: (file: FileType, response: T) => Promise<void> | void
  ) => void;
  onRevert: <T extends any>(
    callback: (file: FileType, response: T) => Promise<void> | void
  ) => void;
  onAbort: (callback: (file: FileType) => Promise<void> | void) => void;
  onRemove: (callback: (file: FileType) => Promise<void> | void) => void;
}

export type BlockStates =
  | "waiting"
  | "uploading"
  | "completed"
  | "aborted"
  | "reverted"
  | "removed";

export const EpicFileBlock = forwardRef<EpicFileBlockRef, EpicFileBlockProps>(
  ({ index, Classes, theme, fileType, remove }, Ref) => {
    const [state] = useState<BlockStates>("waiting");

    const [FileType] = useState(fileType);

    const [, setOnAdd] = useState<(file: FileType) => Promise<void> | void>(
      () => {}
    );

    const [, setOnUpload] = useState<
      (file: FileType, response: any) => Promise<void> | void
    >(() => {});

    const [, setOnRevert] = useState<
      (file: FileType, response: any) => Promise<void> | void
    >(() => {});

    const [, setOnAbort] = useState<(file: FileType) => Promise<void> | void>(
      () => {}
    );

    const [onRemove, setOnRemove] = useState<
      (file: FileType) => Promise<void> | void
    >(() => {});

    const StatusText = (state: BlockStates) => {
      if (state === "waiting") return "Waiting";
      else if (state === "uploading") return "Uploading...";
      else if (state === "completed") return "Completed";
      else if (state === "aborted") return "Aborted";
      else if (state === "reverted") return "Reverted";
      else if (state === "removed") return "Removed";
      else return "Unknown Status";
    };

    //   const FilesList = (...files: File[]) => {
    //     const Transfer = new DataTransfer();
    //     files.forEach((file) => {
    //       if (file instanceof File) Transfer.items.add(file);
    //       else
    //         throw new TypeError(
    //           "Expected argument to FileList is File or Array of File objects"
    //         );
    //     });

    //     return Transfer.files;
    //   };

    const OnAdd = (callback: (file: FileType) => Promise<void> | void) =>
      setOnAdd(callback);

    const OnUpload = <T extends any>(
      callback: (file: FileType, response: T) => Promise<void> | void
    ) => setOnUpload(callback);

    const OnRevert = <T extends any>(
      callback: (file: FileType, response: T) => Promise<void> | void
    ) => setOnRevert(callback);

    const OnAbort = (callback: (file: FileType) => Promise<void> | void) =>
      setOnAbort(callback);

    const OnRemove = (callback: (file: FileType) => Promise<void> | void) =>
      setOnRemove(callback);

    // Put Methods to the Reference
    useImperativeHandle(Ref, () => ({
      onAdd: OnAdd,
      onUpload: OnUpload,
      onRevert: OnRevert,
      onAbort: OnAbort,
      onRemove: OnRemove,
    }));

    return (
      <motion.div
        id={index.toString()}
        initial="hidden"
        animate={state === "removed" ? "hidden" : "visible"}
        variants={{
          hidden: { opacity: 0, marginTop: "-80px" },
          visible: { opacity: 1, marginTop: "0px" },
        }}
        transition={{ duration: 0.3 }}
        className={Classes.blockContainer}
      >
        <motion.div
          initial="slideDown"
          animate={state === "removed" ? "slideDown" : "slideUp"}
          variants={{
            slideDown: { transform: "translateY(100px)" },
            slideUp: { transform: "translateY(0px)" },
          }}
          transition={{ duration: 0.3 }}
          className={[Classes.block, Classes.blockPrimary, theme].join(" ")}
        >
          <div className={Classes.optionsContainer}>
            <div className={Classes.optionsColumn}>
              <p
                className={[
                  Classes.blockText,
                  Classes.blockHeading,
                  theme,
                ].join(" ")}
              >
                {StatusText(state)}
              </p>
              <motion.p
                initial="fadeInDown"
                animate="fadeInUp"
                variants={{
                  fadeInDown: { opacity: 0, transform: "translateY(10px)" },
                  fadeInUp: { opacity: 1, transform: "translateY(0px)" },
                }}
                transition={{ duration: 0.3, delay: 0.2 }}
                className={[Classes.blockText, theme].join(" ")}
              >
                {FileType.name}
              </motion.p>
            </div>
            <div className={Classes.optionsColumn}>
              {/* Controls */}

              {state === "completed" ? (
                <motion.div
                  initial="fadeInDown"
                  animate="fadeInUp"
                  variants={{
                    fadeInDown: { opacity: 0, transform: "translateY(10px)" },
                    fadeInUp: { opacity: 1, transform: "translateY(0px)" },
                  }}
                  transition={{ duration: 0.3, delay: 0.2 }}
                  className={Classes.actionButtonContainer}
                >
                  <button
                    className={[
                      Classes.actionButton,
                      Classes.actionPrimary,
                      theme,
                    ].join(" ")}
                  >
                    <FiRotateCcw />
                  </button>
                </motion.div>
              ) : (
                ""
              )}

              {["waiting", "uploading", "aborted", "reverted"].includes(
                state
              ) ? (
                <Fragment>
                  {state !== "uploading" ? (
                    <Fragment>
                      <motion.div
                        initial="fadeInDown"
                        animate="fadeInUp"
                        variants={{
                          fadeInDown: {
                            opacity: 0,
                            transform: "translateY(10px)",
                          },
                          fadeInUp: {
                            opacity: 1,
                            transform: "translateY(0px)",
                          },
                        }}
                        transition={{ duration: 0.3, delay: 0.2 }}
                        className={Classes.actionButtonContainer}
                      >
                        <button
                          className={[
                            Classes.actionButton,
                            Classes.actionDanger,
                          ].join(" ")}
                          onClick={() => {
                            // setState("removed");
                            setTimeout(async () => {
                              if (typeof onRemove === "function")
                                await onRemove(FileType);
                              return typeof remove === "function"
                                ? remove(FileType)
                                : undefined;
                            }, 1000);
                          }}
                        >
                          <FiX />
                        </button>
                      </motion.div>
                      <motion.div
                        initial="fadeInDown"
                        animate="fadeInUp"
                        variants={{
                          fadeInDown: {
                            opacity: 0,
                            transform: "translateY(10px)",
                          },
                          fadeInUp: {
                            opacity: 1,
                            transform: "translateY(0px)",
                          },
                        }}
                        transition={{ duration: 0.3, delay: 0.2 }}
                        className={Classes.actionButtonContainer}
                      >
                        <button
                          className={[
                            Classes.actionButton,
                            Classes.actionSuccess,
                            theme,
                          ].join(" ")}
                        >
                          <FiUpload />
                        </button>
                      </motion.div>
                    </Fragment>
                  ) : (
                    <motion.div
                      initial="fadeInDown"
                      animate="fadeInUp"
                      variants={{
                        fadeInDown: {
                          opacity: 0,
                          transform: "translateY(10px)",
                        },
                        fadeInUp: { opacity: 1, transform: "translateY(0px)" },
                      }}
                      transition={{ duration: 0.3, delay: 0.2 }}
                      className={Classes.actionButtonContainer}
                    >
                      <button
                        className={[
                          Classes.actionButton,
                          Classes.actionDanger,
                        ].join(" ")}
                      >
                        <FiSlash />
                      </button>
                    </motion.div>
                  )}
                </Fragment>
              ) : (
                ""
              )}
            </div>
          </div>
        </motion.div>
      </motion.div>
    );
  }
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually the Array.map was working properly. The problem was inside the child component that was getting rendered inside the Array.map loop.

The mistake is inside the delete element function (RemoveFiles on index.tsx file):

```
// Old Function
const RemoveFiles = (...fileNames: string[]) => {
      setFiles((list) => {
        list = list.filter((file) => {
          if (fileNames.includes(file.name)) return false;
          else return true;
        });
        return [...list];
      });
    };

// New Function
const RemoveFiles = (...fileNames: string[]) => {
      setFiles((list) => {
        list.forEach((file, index) => {
          if (fileNames.includes(file.name)) delete list[index];
        });
        return [...list];
      });
    };
```

This update will prevent from providing new indexes to all the elements. For example, if I delete element on index 0 then it will keep undefined on index 0 instead of repositioning all the elements. Which will fix the problem.

If I reposition all the elements in the Array then the React will try to load the same states of the deleted element which caused the strange behavior! React will load old states because of key={0} (No matter if the props are updated!).